# How to map POJO field to different table column using jOOQ for inserts?

Tags: java, jooq

Following this example. The MyBook class uses a field which does not match the column definition.

- POJO: "myTitle"
- Table: "title"

```java
public class MyBook {
  public int id;

  // column in database is called "title"
  public String myTitle;
}

MyBook myBook = new MyBook();
myBook.id = 10;
myBook.myTitle = "Animal Farm";

BookRecord book = create.newRecord(BOOK, myBook);

book.store();
```

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/#loading-pojos-back-into-records-to-store-them

The field will not be stored in the database since it can't be mapped. I tried to add `@Column(name = "title")`, but this will only be utilized for me when mapping the results of a query to a POJO.

Comment: The `@Column` annotation should always map to-from the column name. I don't see why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround/solve the issue by adding another getter to my POJO class. In the example a `String getTitle() { return myTitle; }` method would be sufficient.

Sidenote: When using interfaces the getter can be hidden from the remaining code.